# How do you run a PHP script as the file's owner, rather than as the webserver user?

Tags: php, setuid

I'm sure there's a well-known answer for this, but I can't seem to find it.

How do I make a user's PHP scripts (in `~user/public_html`, for example), run as the owner rather than as (eg) `www-data`?

Assume Apache, Linux, and PHP 5.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html).

http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=apache/INSTALL

> The suPHP Apache module together with
>   suPHP itself provides an easy way to
>   run PHP scripts with different users
>   on the same server.
>
> It provides security, because the PHP
>   scripts are not run with the rights of
>   the webserver's user.

Comment: are there any other options?

Comment: if you aren't limiting yourself to apache/mod_php then I think so.  I am pretty sure there is something you can do with fastcgi.

Comment: I tried FastCGI and php-fpm but I can't run them same as how suPHP does. I have a lot of files in my folder which are owned by different users. suPHP allows me to run each file as the owner but fastCGI doesn't do that.. for FastCGI I can only set up static usernames and then it runs with them

Comment: I really didn't dig into this much myself.  You may need to post a new question describing your unique requirements.